# How do I bypass ASP.NET validation

Tags: asp.net, xss

I have legal contract for this purpose.

I was trying to perform XSS attack on a website which uses ASP.NET. It's form validation is preventing me to enter payload. Is there any way to bypass that?

[image]

Comment: I hope not. The "form validation", as you put it, is part of the default setup that is in place to try and prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: Ohk Let's wait for other's answer

Comment: [How to bypass .Net 4.5 request validation, for an XSS attack? - Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/80089/how-to-bypass-net-4-5-request-validation-for-an-xss-attack)

Comment: [Bypassing ValidateRequest in ASP.NET | SANS Institute](https://www.sans.org/blog/bypassing-validaterequest-in-asp-net/)

Comment: @phuzi, if you want to store data from a html editor you need to disable it on that page (but not globally for xss attacht as you mentioned).

Comment: @ShvanshuSingh, add `ValidateRequest="false"` on the aspx's first line and/or add `protected void Page_preInit(object sender, EventArgs e) { Page.EnableEventValidation = false; }` to the code behind. But still validate the contents in the backend for XSS attaks!

Comment: @VDWWD True, you could, I wouldn't do it though. I would sanitise/encode it in the client before hand so that dangerous characters, e.g.`<` becomes `&lt;` which would make it safe to render on the page and I don't have to disable the request validation at all.

Comment: @phuzi, it's been a while since i did webforms, but could it be that `&lt;` also triggers it? Not sure though

Comment: @VDWWD Good question, it's been a while for me too. However I would always look for a solution that didn't involve disabling request validation.

Comment: @phuzi, yes that would indeed be the best and safest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain unicode characters make it through.

But it realy depends what you are trying to achieve. If you need to prove the point that request validation is not enough to protect gainst XSS than you realy need to find such a payload.

The more common task would be: find the parts in the application that are affected by missing encoding of the output. For that you would need remove request validation in a test environment.